# How to pass a template function as template class argument?

Tags: c++, templates

Here's the thing, it seems it's possible to pass a templatized struct which contains some static functions like this:

```
template <class T> struct FunctionHolder {};

template <> struct FunctionHolder<string> {
    static void f(const string &s) {
        cout << "f call " << s << endl;
    }
};

template <class Key, class Value, class Holder = FunctionHolder<Key>>
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(Key k) {
        Holder::f(k);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Foo<string, int> foo = Foo<string, int>("test_string");
}
```

But, would it be possible to pass directly templatized functions without been defined statically on templatized structs? I've tried this and it won't compile:

```
template <class string> static void f(const string &s) {
    cout << "f call " << k << endl;
}

template <class Key, class Value, typename func<Key>> class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(Key k) {
        func(k);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Foo<string, int> foo = Foo<string, int>("test_string");
}
```

Asking this cos it's not cool to be forced to create dummy structures (structures containing a bunch of static functions) to be used as template type of the main class.

Comment: Why not just `func<Key>` in `Foo` ctor? Provide use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately function templates can't be used as [template template arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments); you can use function pointer as the non-type template parameter instead, e.g.

```
template <class Key, class Value, void(*func)(const Key&) = f<Key>> class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(Key k) {
        func(k);
    }
};
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/EYJTKA4322)